# How to create Ruby array sort the same as in AngularJS, lowercase should stand infront of uppercase

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, angularjs, sorting

I'm writing test for Rails app with AngularJS where I want to check that sort on site works proper.
On front-end clicking on sort button (orderBy:sort.column:sort.descending) this array:

`arr = ["B kitty", "K kitty", "A kitty", "Z kitty", "b kitty", "L kitty", "S kitty", "q kitty", "c kitty"]`

is sorted as:

`sorted_arr = ["A kitty", "b kitty", "B kitty", "c kitty", "K kitty", "L kitty", "q kitty", "S kitty", "Z kitty"]`

so that `"b kitty"` is infront of `"B kitty"`.

But I cannot create the same sort method in Ruby to sort arr as expected, instead I always get "B kitty" infront of "b kitty".

Is there any way to achive this in my test?

Comment: What code are you using to sort?

Comment: Well in this case I would consider the AngularJS behavior unexpected, as capital letters do precede lower case ones in the ASCII and therefore also in the Unicode charset. If you desire caseless comparison you can use `arr.sort(&:casecmp)` in `ruby`, but that will leave the order of `"b kitty"` and `"B kitty"` unspecified as it should be expected. Could you be more specific on the ruby code you use to sort?

Comment: Thanks guys for help, I tried to create custom sort, but seems that I need more practice in it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think AngularJS just [downcase the values and sort](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/aa268560064e5875bd471da3f7d1ebc2f9e6b3b7/src/ng/filter/orderBy.js#L151), and the result just happens to be that `b kitty` is in front of `B kitty`. The result isn't stable. (Correct me if I have wrong assumption).

If you want stable behavior in your Ruby code to get the *unstable* sort result from AngularJS, you can do it like this:

```
arr.sort{|a, b| (c = a.downcase <=> b.downcase) == 0 ? b <=> a : c }
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! Looks like this is the same that BroiSatse wrote, but with ternary and I like more your code.

Comment: And yes, I think also that AngularJS sort result is unstable, there is no really preferences about `b kitty` and `B kitty`, but for tests I really need something stable. Actually I understand that comparing `stable and unstable` is not the best way.

Answer (score 1):

`arr.sort_by{|s| s.downcase}`
If you don't mind `"b kitty"` and `"B kitty"` having the same weight.

Otherwise you need a custom sort.

```
arr.sort do |s1, s2|
  if s1.downcase == s2.downcase
    s2 <=> s1
  else
    s1.downcase <=> s2.downcase
  end
end
```

Use the bang `!` operator if you want to change `arr` itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
arr = ["B kitty", "K kitty", "A kitty", "Z kitty", "b kitty", "L kitty", "S kitty", "q kitty", "c kitty"]

arr.sort do |first, second|
  result = first.casecmp(second)
  result = second <=> first if result.zero?
  result
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr.sort_by{|x|[x.downcase,-x[0].ord]}
```

Comment: this might answer the question but its better to explain your answer in context to the asked question